# Automatically edit row based on date

Tags: php, date, cron

I am currently trying to create a script/function that should set a value to all items (eshop goods) old 15 days or older.

This script will be used as cron.

Date is stored in database as integer, but I don't exactly know how to approach the 15 days gap.

Could somebody help me out please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
$integer_format = strtotime("-15 days"); 
$dateTime_format = date("Y-m-d h:i:s A T",$integer_format);
echo 'In integer format: '.$integer_format.'</br>'; //1403953190
echo 'In date time format: '.$dateTime_format.'</br>'; //2014-06-28 12:59:50 PM CEST
```